# How to fix 500 Code Server Error Next JS API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, openai-api

I am trying to build a chat bot with the OPEN AI GPT 4 Model in NextJS. However when I send a POST request to http://localhost:3001/api/generate I get a Response with status code 500 and this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers').

/app/api/generate/route.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configutation = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configutation);

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const body = await request.json();
  const { prompt } = body;

  if (!prompt || prompt === "") {
    return new Response("Please send your prompt", { status: 400 });
  }

  try {
    const aiResult = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "gpt-4",
      prompt,
      temperature: 0.9,
      max_tokens: 8192,
    });
    const aiText =
      aiResult.data.choices[0].text?.trim() || "Something went wrong!";

    return NextResponse.json({ text: aiText });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I'm new to NextJS 13 but when I try sending a static response like "Hello World" I don't encounter any errors

Comment: You can gradually comment parts of your code to find the one causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js API routes expect a request object as the first argument, not a request object. Therefore, you need to change `request: Request` to `req: NextApiRequest` in your code. Additionally, you need to change the response object from Response to NextResponse.

for request,
from this

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
```

to this

```
export default async function generateAPI(req: NextApiRequest) {
```

for response,
from this

```
return new Response("Please send your prompt", { status: 400 });
```

to this

```
return new NextResponse("Please send your prompt", { status: 400 });
```